# Tumblr How to add Lightbox FancyBox3 for Video YouTube link?

Tags: jquery, video, fancybox, lightbox, tumblr

my single photo and multiple photo lightbox popup is working on my blog. But Video lightbox popup is not working.
What am i doing wrong here?

But how can I add FancyBox3 to my Tumblr blog (https://ozarking-1.tumblr.com/, Videos, YouTube links and mix media etc.

```
<!-- TEST start-->
<!-- fancybox3 Lightbox Tumblr-->
{block:iflightbox}
{block:Video}

<a data-fancybox href="{VideoEmbed-700}" <img src="{block:VideoThumbnail}
{VideoThumbnailURL}
{/block:VideoThumbnail}"/></a>

{/block:Video}
{/block:iflightbox}
<!-- TEST end-->
```

Answer (score 0):

fancybox just works if you have done everything correctly. Your code seems to be missing  `>`, e.g.,

`<a data-fancybox href="{VideoEmbed-700}" <img src="`

should be

`<a data-fancybox href="{VideoEmbed-700}"> <img src="`

So, check the output of your code and make sure it is a valid HTML.